# Exporting large high resolution map to PDF in ArcMap errors?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, pdf, resolution

I am attempting to export a large E size map at 300 DPI in ArcMap 10.2.2 but each time I export there are errors on the map.  Once the PDF is generated there are areas where symbols are stretched out in a line across the width of the map.  I have tried it on ArcMap 10.1 and 10.2.2 and I get the same errors.  I know I can avoid these errors if I export at a lower DPI, but I want a really high resolution print of this particular map to be prominently displayed.  All other parameters for the export to PDF are the default values.

Here is an example of the errors: [image: example of the errors.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last time I saw that (the symbology leak) I had to fix a self intersection in a polygon.
That could be the reason for the error.
 But higher resolution pdf creation does take some extra configuration.
Make sure you have plenty of virtual ram set.
Make sure there is plenty of disk space on your temp drive. Ussually c drive.

I think I remember something in the arcgis advance settings.
Look in C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\Utilities\AdvancedArcMapSettings.exe

Comment: I've increased my virtual ram to 20,000 MB from 4,960 MB but I still get the same errors at 300 dpi.  I'm not sure how to access the arcgis advanced settings.

Comment: @cbunn The advanced settings is a standalone exe utility that must be run with all other Arc programs closed. You can find it at C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\Utilities on a default install. Be careful when changing things, as this is essentially editing registry keys.

Comment: If I change a value in the Advanced settings I can always change it back right? Do you believe increasing the polygon vertex limits for PDF will eliminate this error?

Comment: yes you can change it back. run it with arcmap closed as admin.

Comment: have you run repair geometry on (it looks like two different polygons possibly two different layers) the data that is leaking out?

Comment: Repaired the geometry of the layers that were experiencing the errors and was able to whittle it down to a single stripe of leaked symbology.  Upon further inspection of the layer experiencing the leak I found lots of "slivers" tacked onto polygons throughout the layer.  I merged my multipart polygon layer in ArcGIS 10.2.2 to eliminate the slivers and included it back into the .mxd and the leaky symbology vanished when exported at 150 dpi.  When I exported it at 300 dpi another layer experienced the leaky symbology issue and I merged that layer together and was able to export it at 300 dpi.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the offset 0.0001. It won't show a difference, but it forces arcmap to redraw the symbology of the feature.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using this Python snippet in the ArcMap Python Window to narrow things down:

```
mapDoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current")
... layerList = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mapDoc)
... for layer in layerList:
...     if layer.isRasterizingLayer:
...         print layer.name + " is RASTERIZING"
...         
cnty24k13_1_poly is RASTERIZING
cnty24k13_1_poly is RASTERIZING
Pacific Ocean Bathymetry is RASTERIZING
cal_ocean_alb is RASTERIZING
Battalions is RASTERIZING
USA Water Body Types is RASTERIZING
SRA14_1 is RASTERIZING
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest De-fragmenting ArcGIS Documnet. That will reduce the size of your document by half and will be easy to draw.
http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.1/ArcGISDevHelp/DeveloperTools/MXDDefrag.htm